# Android - compile C library

Tags: android, c, makefile, android-ndk

I need to compile libmysqlclient and librtlstr for Android (in fact I could find rtlsdr, but since I need mysqlclient the issue is still there).
I followed several guides but most of them present the instruction written here http://mortoray.com/2012/08/21/android-ndk-cross-compile-setup-libpng-and-freetype/

Anyway, the package I download did not contain any configure file so I don't know how to continue.

Because the purpose of this file should only be the creation of the makefile, maybe there is a way solve this.

So my questions are:

1) Is this the right approach? Are there others easier?

2) Does a general configure file exist so that I can download and use it?

3)If not, how does the makefile has to be written? This way I should be able to overcome the abscence of configure file

I need those libraries to port a c code (which needs them) to android building an executable that I'll run on my phone (so I already have the standalone toolchain from the NDK), if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is right approach (may be a little bit simplified, I'm using more steps to build) for libraries, which use [automake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake). Much easier, if library uses [Cmake](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html) (must contain CMakeLists.txt), because you need only NDK. Example: `cmake -DANDROID_NDK=path/to/ndk -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 ..`

2) No, also you need provide additional files (for example, `Makefile.in`)

3) This libraries have to use one of tools such CMake, automake etc, just `Makefile` or project for some IDE. So, try to find out, what of this use your libraries

Comment: Well, in the package there is a CMakeList.txt and a folder "CMake", so I suppose I am lucky. Still, I'm a newbie, so help me clarify: I just have to run the line of code you wrote (for example) in the package directory and that's all?

Comment: If Cmake installed and added to Path, library doesn't need additional flags - yes (but you should execute this line in package subdirectory (usually create dir for this - `build`) (due to `..` - this is relative path to top CMakeLists.txt). When configuration and generation of `Makefile` ended successfully, you can build your library for ARM (due to `armeabi-v7a` in my example) just by executing `make` (or `cmake --build .`) in same directory.

If you have other questions - asks freely